# incorrect logic in checksum function

Tags: java, object

```
public class CreditCardNumber {
private String issuerID = "000000";
private String accountNum = "999999999";
private int checkDigit = 0;

public CreditCardNumber(String TempissuerID, String TempaccountNum) {
    if (TempissuerID != null && TempaccountNum != null
            && TempissuerID.length() == 6 && TempaccountNum.length() == 9)
        if (Digits(TempissuerID) && Digits(TempaccountNum)) {
            issuerID = TempissuerID;
            accountNum = TempaccountNum;
            calcCheckDigits();
        }
}

public boolean Digits(String temp1) {
    String temp = "0123456789";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp1.length(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.length(); j++)
            if (temp1.charAt(i) == temp.charAt(j)) {
                count++;

            }
    if (count == temp1.length()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public CreditCardNumber() {
}

public String getID() {
    return issuerID;
}

public String getAccNum() {
    return accountNum;
}

public int getDigits() {
    return checkDigit;
}

private void calcCheckDigits() {
    int sum;
    sum = checkSum();
    if ((sum + checkDigit) % 10 != 0) {
        checkDigit = sum - (sum % 10);
    }
    System.out.printf("%d", checkDigit);
}

public void CreateCred(String TempissuerID) {
    if (TempissuerID != null && TempissuerID.length() == 6
            && Digits(TempissuerID)) {
        issuerID = TempissuerID;
    } else {
        issuerID = "000000";
    }
    StringBuilder TempString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        TempString = TempString.append((Math.random() * (9 - 0 + 1) + 0));
    }
    accountNum = TempString.toString();
    calcCheckDigits();
}

private int checkSum() {
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    int num;
    int sum = 0;
      for(int i = 0 ; i <issuerID.length();i++)
         {
                 temp = temp.append(issuerID.charAt(i));
         }
                 for(int j = 0 ; j < accountNum.length(); j++)
                 {            
                     temp = temp.append(accountNum.charAt(j));
                 }

    System.out.println(temp);
    for (int k = 0; k < temp.length(); k += 2) {
        num = temp.charAt(k) - '0';
        num *= 2;
        if (num > 9)
            num = 1 + (num % 10);
        temp.setCharAt(k, (char) num);
    }
    for (int v = 0; v < temp.length(); v++) {
        sum += temp.charAt(v) - '0';
    }
    System.out.printf("%d", sum);
    return sum;
}

public String toString() {
    String s = "";
        String str = issuerID + accountNum;

        return str;
    }
}
```

I have a problem in my checksum method, I wrote some printf statement to check for the value of sum which turn out to be -930 but This is not what the value sum suppose to be , if adding only there is no reason for it to have a negative sign.I am expecting the checkDigit number to be 9 when I enter  321321 for issuerID and 654654654 for accountNum, and the value of sum in check sum will be passed to the calCheckDigits method to get the value for CheckDigit which is 9.

What am I doing wrong in this method?

ok I just edit the code now I get -30 for the sum

I just edit again my first 2 for loops  in checksum was wrong leading my temp string value to be incorrect

now it get -320
still incorrect but getting better

Comment: You should try to narrow down your code or something. Not all of it is relevant, and it just gives us more to look at. And what value were you expecting for sum?

Comment: I haven't read the code extensively, but could the checksum be negative because it is overflowing the maximum integer size? Perhaps try smaller input to see if it returns correctly.

Comment: i just edit the post with more information so the input I use is 321321 for issuerID and 654654654 for accountNum and that was the test run input for this assignment

Comment: ok i narrow it down to this line right here temp.setCharAt(k, (char) num); in checksum fucntion somehow because i use it in a loop and it add up each time it go through the loop making the sum value  big

Comment: @user1787811: Please *edit* your post to include *just* the relevant code. Also, indent your code more sensibly so it's easy to read.

Comment: It is normal that a checksum overflow and come negative, you must use unsigned but in java it doesn't exits. The key is only that everytime you calculate the checksum the result is the same when the data is ok.